# using create-react-app and Sublimelinter ESlint together

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3, eslint, sublimelinter

I use facebook's **[create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html)**, which intentionally hide all the configuration setup, and leave us with a lovely simple file structure

[image: a lovely file structure]

That's great! but there's one really annoying thing that come up:

**SublimeLinter is no longer works
because the .eslintrc configuration file is not longer at the root of the project.**

### Key points

- I know I can put another .eslintrc file at the root,
  but I would like to be able to set my rules in one place
- I know it is possible to `npm eject` to get the entire project structure out in front, but I would like to keep things simple. otherwise it becomes [just another boilerplate](http://andrewhfarmer.com/starter-project/)
- I noticed that in the package.json
  [image: a clue inside the package.json]

### What I already tried?

a direction I thought about is to change:

```
"eslintConfig": {
   "extends": "./node_modules/react-scripts/config/eslint.js"
}
```

to:

```
"eslintConfig": {
   "extends": "./.eslintrc.js"
}
```

but it seems to require all the eslint-plugins (which are magically hidden from `node_modules`) so I'm not sure it's the right way.

Any insights?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> SublimeLinter is no longer works because the .eslintrc configuration file is not longer at the root of the project.

This is not correct.

SublimeLinter will work just fine *but* you currently have to install a few things globally. The generated project’s README includes the [instructions to get linter IDE integration working](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/template/README.md#displaying-lint-output-in-the-editor):

> Finally, you will need to install some packages globally:
>
> ```
> npm install -g eslint babel-eslint eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-flowtype
> ```
>
> We recognize that this is suboptimal, but it is currently required due to the way we hide the ESLint dependency. The ESLint team is already [working on a solution to this](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/3458) so this may become unnecessary in a couple of months.

This is, of course, assuming that you’re fine with the ESLint configuration we picked for you.

Comment: Actually Dan, it's working fine for me just installing them **locally**. Is that possible?

Comment: That works too, sure, if you're okay with a bunch of devDependencies.

Comment: I find it actually cleaner, and it will be version-proof.

Comment: I also had to install eslint-config-react-app and the docs are now at https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#displaying-lint-output-in-the-editor (Dan's link is broken)

Comment: 404. Is this the correct link? [Displaying Lint Output in the Editor](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#displaying-lint-output-in-the-editor)

Comment: Hi, is this still the state of the art? Thanks for any help